# Add a character to a frequency list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have a project about huffman coding, and I am stuck, I don't understand why my code is not working.

This is the exercise:

> Write a function `add1` which, given a character, adds 1 to its frequency in a frequency list. If the character is not yet in the list of frequencies, it is added.

```
(add1 "e" '(("l" 1) ("e" 2) ("x" 1)))       →          (("l" 1) ("e" 3) ("x" 1)) 
(add1 "e" '(("a" 4) ("b" 3)))               →          (("a" 4) ("b" 3) ("e" 1))
```

What I wrote:

```
(define add1
  (lambda (c l) 
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (if (member? c l)
            (if (equal? c (caar l))
                (+ 1 (cadar l))
                (add1 c (cdr l)))
            (append l '((c 1)))))
        ))
```

The result:

```
(list (list "l" 1) (list "e" 2) (list "x" 1) (list 'c 1))
```

Comment: Which teaching language?

Comment: Scheme, using DrRacket.

Comment: Si tu as du mal avec l'anglais, tu seras certainement intéressé par le projet de site [Stack Overflow en français](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50998/stack-overflow-in-french?referrer=2lF5gAel4pd5yrzOkq_s8g2). Cela dit il est difficile à un programmeur ou à un scientifique de se passer de l'anglais dans sa vie professionnelle.

Comment: Hehe english is not a problem, actually i have more problems with french..but at the university the classes are in french, and the exercise was in french and somehow i just forgot to translate everything..Thank you for the french site,i am definitely going to check it out, i might find something useful:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to call `add1` the procedure, that clashes with a built-in procedure of the same name. Try this instead:

```
(define add-one
  (lambda (c l)
    (cond ((null? l)
           (list (list c 1)))
          ((equal? (caar l) c)
           (cons (list c (+ 1 (cadar l))) (cdr l)))
          (else
           (cons (car l) (add-one c (cdr l)))))))
```

See how, if we reach an empty list, it's because the character wasn't found in the list, so we must add it at the end. The other two cases are self-explanatory: either the character is the current one, or the character is in the rest of the list. By writing the solution in this way, it's not necessary to use `member?`. It works as expected:

```
(add-one "e" '(("l" 1) ("e" 2) ("x" 1)))
=> (("l" 1) ("e" 3) ("x" 1)) 

(add-one "e" '(("a" 4) ("b" 3)))
=> (("a" 4) ("b" 3) ("e" 1))
```

Comment: Could you also tell me what was the problem with mine? ( Beause even tho i understand how the code you wrote works, i still cant see why mine didn't..)

Comment: @user3104814 your code didn't work because you're not actually _building_ a list as output, there isn't a single `cons` in it. And when you're appending, you pass the list of symbols `'((c 1))`, which evaluates to `((c 1))`, that's not the same as `(list (list c 1))`, which takes into consideration the _value_ of `c`, instead of the _symbol_ `c`

Comment: That's because comments are not for this. Delete all the last comments, post them in a separate question, _in english_ please, and make them a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Remember, nobody knows what's your assignment, so you'll have to provide an explanation as if you were telling a 5-year-old, with plenty of examples, with sample input and expected output, and posting the code you've written so far - people won't help you if you expect them to write the code for you, without some previous effort from your part.

Comment: Thank you, will do it as you said.