# Frequency list 2 - Huffman project

Tags: scheme, racket, huffman-code

Previously I had the question about adding a character to a frequency list([Add a character to a frequency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596944/add-a-character-to-a-frequency-list/20597617?noredirect=1#comment30820335_20597617)), it got solved, but i have problems again with the rest of the project. The next 2 functions are working:

*Write a function which creates the frequency list( from a list of characters)*

```
(statistiques '("a" "b" "r" "a" "c" "a" "d" "a" "b" "r" "a")) 
 → (("a" 5) ("r" 2) ("b" 2) ("d" 1) ("c" 1))
```

My code:

```
(define statistiques 
  (lambda (l)
    (if (null? l)
        l
        (ajoute1(car l)(statistiques (cdr l))))))
```

*Write a function which is inserting a pair (a character and a number which indicates the occurrence of that character in a list), in a list of pairs which is sorted by the number of occurrence*

```
(inserefreq '("b" 2) '(("d" 1) ("a" 5))) 
 → (("d" 1) ("b" 2) ("a" 5))

(define inserefreq
  (lambda (c l)
    (cond ((null? l) 
           (list c))
      ((<= (cadr c) (cadar l))
           (cons c l))
          (else
           (cons (car l) (inserefreq c (cdr l)))))))*
```

Then the problem is with the next one, which is asking to sort a frequency list by successive insertion

```
(triefreq '(("a" 5) ("r" 2) ("b" 2) ("d" 1) ("c" 1))) 
 → (("d" 1) ("c" 1) ("r" 2) ("b" 2) ("a" 5))
```

My code:

```
(define tirefreq
  (lambda (l)
    (inserefreq(car l) (tirefreq (cdr l)))))
```

Result/error:    [image: error]

Comment: In your previous question someone wanted to know what language you were using and you said "Scheme" (as I understood as #!r6rs), but on your posted image here you are not using Scheme, but "Beginning student with List abbreviations". Your languages has restrictions so it's important to mention that in your questions or else you'll either get #!racket or #!r6rs answers.

Comment: Oh I didn't know.. in class we have the exercises saying "write in Scheme", but we actually always use either this option or the Pretty Big, so i thought these are afterall all the language Scheme, but just slightly different versions of it..(probably i misunderstood a few things said in class,since its in french haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the base case, when `l` is empty:

```
(define triefreq
  (lambda (l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (inserefreq (car l) (triefreq (cdr l))))))
```

Comment: Ohh thank you, i have no idea how i didn't notice this..i feel so dumb:$

Comment: Maybe it's time for a break ;-)